# How one can check the size of the file-object without destroying it?

Tags: python, seek, werkzeug, file-storage

I have an object (called "img") of the `werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage` class (this object represents a file). I need to save this file on the disk. I can do it in the following way:

```
img.save(fname)
```

It works fine. But before I save the file, I need to check its size. I do it in the following way:

```
img.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = img.tell()
```

It works also fine. But the problem is that I cannot save the file after I check its size. Or, more precisely, I get a file on the disk but it is empty, if I checked its size before.

How can I check the size of the file without "destroying" it?

Comment: What if you use os.stat or os.path.getsize(path)?

Comment: If I use `os.stat(value).st_size` I get: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FileStorage found`

Comment: It seems like the "seek head" of the file is at the end by default. Therefore one needs to seek to the file start even if seek wasn't used before.

Answer (score 8):

you forgot to seek the file to its beginning before saving it, hence the empty file

```
#seek to the end of the file to tell its size
img.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = img.tell()

#seek to its beginning, so you might save it entirely
img.seek(0)    
img.save(fname)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of seek and tell replace with:

```
import os
img.flush()
size = os.fstat(img.fileno()).st_size
```

Answer (score 2):

Werkzeug's FileStorage has a `content_length` property: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.content_length

```
img.content_length
```

Comment: However, note that `The content-length sent in the header. Usually not available`. This will only be helpful if the `content-length` header is set correctly by the uploader.